# Magento 2: how to put extra text / drop down for decimal qty

Tags: magento2, addtocart, inventory, product-page

I need to customize the `addtocart.phtml` in order to add an extra field for decimal qty.

I want to use the actual input text for quantities in order to use **ONLY** unit and I need to create another drop down in order to select half quantity. (See picture)

Here is an example of what I need:
https://www.fabric.com/buy/eu-376/north-american-wildlife-abstract-ocean

As you can see, in this product page, there is qty in yard and then a drop down for 0 and 1/2 yard.

I need exactly something like that! 
How can I do it?

PS I don't need to keep track of the inventory, but of course the quantity have to calculate the right price.

Thank you!! [image]

Answer (score 1):

Alright. I did find a solution, but I would like to know what you guys think about it.
It doesn't seem to be the best solution in my opinion, but was the best I found so far.

Basically I created the dropdown, renamed the old qty and created another input text (then hid with css).

Here is my code:

```
<?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <!-- THE ONKEYPRESS MEANS WE CAN ONLY PUT NUMBERS -->
            <div class="field qty">
                <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <span class="edit-qty minus" onclick="minusQty('qty')">-</span>
                    <input type="number"
                           id="qty"
                           maxlength="12"
                           onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'
                           value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                           title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                           data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                           />
                    <span class="edit-qty plus" onclick="plusQty('qty')">+</span>
                </div>
            <span class = "yardText">Yards</span>
        </div>
        <div class="field qty">
                <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
                    <select id = "qty-half" class = "input-text">
                        <option value = "0">0</option>
                        <option value = "0.5">½ </option>
                    </select>
            <span class = "yardText">Half Yard</span>
        </div>
        <input type ="number" name = "qty" value = "0" id = "sumYard" />
```

This is the simple javascript (the onClick is used on the add to cart button):

```
<script>
    function calcSum() {
        var num1 = document.getElementById('qty').value;
        var num2 = document.getElementById('qty-half').value;
        var sum = Number(num1) + Number(num2);
        document.getElementById("sumYard").value = sum;
    }
</script>
```

What do you think? Is it a good solution? Do you guys know something better?

Thanks

Comment: What if you would hide default input [id="qty"] and populate that qty field using JS code with calculation of those visible input boxes: txtQuantity and ddlSize?

Answer (score 0):

Use custom options functionality. Then you will not face troubles saving this value and save much time. If you especially need to move it near the QTY field - you may use CSS.

Navigate

> Adminarea > Catalog > Products > {Edit your product} > {Section "Customizable Options" }

Then I did sth like this.

[image]

**After that, I gon on the frontend following result:**

[image]

**Then using CSS just customize it as you like**

[image]

If you need - you may change options labels (remove text +...$). If you need to add this to many products - just look at catalog_product_option_* tables and generate similar values for all of your products.

Comment: Uhm, what do you mean? Can you please share more details about it? Thanks!
PS, I'm not having a problem in creating the input txt or the dropdown. The problem here is how to add the extra value to the quantity.

Comment: I put more explanation to my post

Comment: Yes, this looked like a pretty good solution. The problem is that when you add to the cart, the qty doesn't change at all. I need to see the quantity to be like 1.5 if the user puts the 1/2 yds. How can I change the quantity if the user gets the 1/2 yard?